# How to use properties file in mirth channel and where we write code for it

Tags: properties-file, mirth, mirth-connect

I want to access channel source and destination file path from property file. Is it possible to use properties file in mirth?

Answer (score 0):

The source and destination file path for a channel is stored in whatever database solution you've elected to use. If you left it at default it will likely use a Derby flat file database, otherwise you can query this by reviewing the schema in whatever RDBMS you've chosen. It's not recommended to modify the data in the Mirth database directly as it could cause data loss.

If you're saying you want to set the source or destination file path based on data in another file, you could do this using JavaScript to fetch the paths out of a file, write them to the channel map, then reference that variable when specifying the file path.